# How to set the distance between figures with subcaption

Tags: spacing

How I can control the distance between figures without modify the width?

For example suppose I have 3 images of width `0.20\linewidth`. If I add another image of width `0.20\linewidth` it will fit on the same row, but I want this 4th image to go to the 2nd row, and set in `0.1\linewidth` the distance between the 3 first images.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{way 1\label{AA.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 2\label{AA.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 3\label{AA.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}}
%
\subcaptionbox{Forma 4\label{AA.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}}
\subcaptionbox{Forma 5\label{AA.eps}}
{\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}}
%\subcaptionbox{AA\label{AA.eps}}
%{\includegraphics[width=.0\linewidth]{AA.eps}}
\caption{5 formas de generar vecindarios.}\label{fig:5formas}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the line using double back slashes `\\[.5cm]` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a comment character `%` to separate the figure construction in the code, use an empty line and *specify* the vertical distance using `\vspace` (or something similar):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{A}
    {\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{B}
    {\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subcaptionbox{C}
    {\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

  \vspace{\baselineskip}

  \subcaptionbox{A}
    {\includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{B}
    {\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Above the empty line following the three sub-figures moves TeX into vertical mode. Then, `\vspace{\baselineskip}` inserts an empty/blank line in the output, after which the second set of the two sub-figures are inserted (horizontally).

Note that it's more intuitive to specify a vertical length when using `\vspace` rather than a horizontal length (like `\linewidth`).

Comment: I have seen in many topics you using `example-image-a` to exemplify something. Well, are these files available in TeXlive distro or did you created them?

Comment: @Sigur: The example figures are all part of the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) by [Martin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2975/martin-scharrer) (see [New support package for MWEs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2470/5764)). It should be available in both MiKTeX *and* TeX Live. People rarely include the package, yet it is available as files from your TDS for usage in MWEs, making it one of the most valuable packages that receives very little recognition/visibility. In my example above, it would also be sufficient to include [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) instead.

Comment: thanks so much for introducing me to `mwe`. Since I have full installed TeXlive I have it. I'll read its documentation.